# Swift: Trouble getting rid of "dim"

Tags: ios, swift

I have been following this tutorial: http://www.totem.training/swift-ios-tips-tricks-tutorials-blog/ux-chops-dim-the-lights

However I have edited it slightly so that I can specify different `Segues` and also do it programmatically.

The problem occurs when I close the popped up view. When I close it, the background dim stays there:

[image]

## What I did to the project files:

files: (https://github.com/TotemTraining/DimBackground.git)

1) Deleted the Segue that was there

2) Created an `IBAction` for the button named **clickedButton**

3) Created new `Segue` from first VC to second Named the Segue **testSegue**

4) Added this code for the `IBAction`:

```
@IBAction func clickedButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("testSegue", sender: self)
}
```

5) Changed the **prepareForSegue** to:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "testSegue") {
    dim(.In, alpha: dimLevel, speed: dimSpeed)
    }
}
```

Now, When I run it, it shows the popup the desired way however when I click the close it removed it but leaves the "Dim" there. Can anyone see why?

The view is going to have several segues from it and I only want a few of them to have this "dim" effect.

Edit:

If I take out the **if (segue.identifier == "testSegue")** so its now:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //if (segue.identifier == "testSegue") {
    dim(.In, alpha: dimLevel, speed: dimSpeed)
    //}
}
```

it works as desired, so is it something to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your unwind isn't getting called in order to dim out.  Have you set a breakpoint to make sure?  Also, if you are using Xcode 8, there was a weird bug with unwind segue names.  They automatically got appended with "WithSegue:" at the end of them, so double check that it is labeled correctly in Interface Builder.